# Getting error while generating pojo from xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to convert xml to java bean. Below is the XML string. Class generated from http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/. while executing the program

```
OrderByDate o=new OrderByDate();        
String xml=o.fetchOrder();
JAXBContext jaxbContext;
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( ListOrdersResponse.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();       
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);        
ListOrdersResponse customer = (ListOrdersResponse) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
System.out.println(customer);
```

error:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01", local:"ListOrdersResponse"). Expected elements are <{}ListOrdersResponse>
```

xml:

Response:
RequestId: 4517462f-bcc9-4a45-8636-b5ddb7ec2758
Timestamp: 2018-04-17T07:20:19.748Z
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2018-04-17T07:18:19Z408-2380372-7405902408-2380372-74059022018-02-02T03:31:55Z2018-02-02T08:57:30ZShippedAFNAmazon.inStandardrajiv sharmahouse no 117  sector 1  jail land ambala cityhouse no 117 sector 1 jail landAMBALAHARYANA134003ININR483.0010OtherStandardA21TJRUUN4KGV4kbdx30tbk39pc4@marketplace.amazon.inpriyam bhardwajStandardStandardOrder2018-02-02T18:29:59Z2018-02-02T18:29:59Zfalsefalsefalsefalse4517462f-bcc9-4a45-8636-b5ddb7ec2758

Comment: It's not XML but JSON...

Answer (score 0):

You should use Jackson parser:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(yourString);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the way you have generated your class is... let's say somewhat unorthodox. http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/ apparently takes XML or JSON and generates a Java bean based on that XML or JSON. While this may work in some cases, this absolutely does not guarantee that it will work correctly for *other* XML/JSON complying to the same schema.

To shorten up, you should not generate classes based on XML/JSON examples, you should generate classes from XML Schema (or JSON Schema).

Now, to your question. Your class apparently lacks the namespace. Add the following `package-info.java` to the same package where you have `ListOrdersResponse`:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package whatever.your.package.is;
```

This assumes that the schema uses `elementFormDefault="qualified"`, i.e. local elements belong to the same `https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01` namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So now I have to create a java file and it that I have to add  @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package whatever.your.package.is;